# Javascript - Open Popup automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the reveal popup and its working fine when I click on the link to open it. However, what I am trying to do now is to open automatically on open the page (pageload).

How can I achieve this?

here is my code so far:

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">open poup</a>    

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
...something....
</div> 


 $(function () {
        $(window).bind('load',
            function (e) {
                $('#myModal')
            });
    });
```

I have tried it with javascript with page load, window load etc.. but nothing is working

Comment: You should edit your question and post the javascript part.

Comment: Can you add some of your Javascript so we can debug?

Comment: Purely from a usability perspective, please don't do this. It's a horrible way to use a site, and I for one adblock these kind of things anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the function in:

A $( document ).ready() block.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

// Do here...
});
```

Or either:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    console.log( "window loaded" );
});
```

Comment: In addition, the OP's code `$('#myModal')` does nothing. If they are correct that clicking the link works properly, they most likely they simply need to add an id to the link, and trigger the onClick, such as `$("a#myPopupLink").click()`, or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

```
<body onload="javascript:yourNastyUglyPopupFunction()">
```

is this working? If not then your function is not properly defined or your pop-up is blocked by adBlock or browser itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using <  body onload="javascript function to run"  >

Most UI libraries, like JQuery, also allow you to run functions upon document load.